# C++ STL - Inserting a custom class as a mapped value

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class:

```
class Monster : public Player
{
public:
    // Copy constructor - used for populating monster list in Game class
    Monster(int newType)
    {
        type = newType;
        canmove = true;
        notforward = false;
    }

    int type;

    bool operator==(const Monster& m) const {return type == m.type;}
    bool operator!=(const Monster& m) const {return type != m.type;}
    bool operator< (const Monster& m) const {return type <  m.type;}
    bool operator<=(const Monster& m) const {return type <= m.type;}
    bool operator> (const Monster& m) const {return type >  m.type;}
    bool operator>=(const Monster& m) const {return type >= m.type;}
};
```

Some variables (like canmove and notforward) are inherited.  Next, in a different class, I create a map of monsters:

```
map<pair<int, int>, Monster> monsters; // Pair used for x and y coordinate

monsters.insert(make_pair(10, 10), Monster(10)); 
// Error - No instance of overloaded function
```

How can I get the Monster instances into the monsters map?  I added all the operator overloads just so I could insert, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Why does this say "win32"?  It has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I am having trouble with this, did you find a solution to it? The solution posted on this page did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is

```
monsters[make_pair(10, 10)] = Monster(10);
```

another way is

```
monsters.insert(make_pair(make_pair(10, 10), Monster(10)));
```

yet another is

```
monsters.insert(map<pair<int, int>, Monster>::value_type(make_pair(10, 10), Monster(10)));
```

Operator overloads are unnecessary, you do need to overload operator< for the *key* of a map but not for the value. I think maybe you got confused because two calls to make_pair are necessary in the second case.

Comment: AH!  OF COURSE!  It's always the simple things.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianGradin I should add that the first example does require Monster to have a default constructor, which isn't the case in the posted code.