# Creating a map and inserting custom class element to it in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash

I want to create a map that uses my custom class as the key and element. However, I am getting errors when inserting. I have found a post related to my question here, [C++ STL - Inserting a custom class as a mapped value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475141/c-stl-inserting-a-custom-class-as-a-mapped-value). But the solution proposed did not help me.

```
/*
 * Structure for a coordinate
 * This is the custom class that I created 
 */
class Coord{ 
    public:
        int x, y;

    public:
        Coord(int x1, int y1) {
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }
        int getX(void) {
            return x;
        }
        int getY(void) {
            return y;
        }
};

/*
 * I attempted to create a map<Coord, Coord>
 * and attempted to insert Coord values in. I get
 * compile time error
 */
map<Coord, Coord> came_from; 
came_from.insert(Coord(0,0), Coord(5,5));
```

I get this error.

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('Coord' and 'Coord')
for (const_iterator __e = cend(); __f != __l; ++__f)
                                              ~~~ ^  ~~~
```

What does this mean?

**Edit 1**

Actually order doesn't matter for me, so I think unordered_map is more appropriate in this case.

I changed to unordered_map and used emplace as suggested in comment. New Code below:

```
unordered_map<Coord, Coord> came_from; 
came_from.emplace(Coord(0,0), Coord(0,0));
```

I get a an error indicating the hash function is not meeting requirements. Below are the exact error messages.

```
static_assert failed due to requirement '__check_hash_requirements<__hash_value_type<Coord, Coord>,
      int>::value' "the specified hash does not meet the Hash requirements"
    static_assert(__check_hash_requirements<_Key, _Hash>::value,
```

I guess I need to define a custom hash function right? How do I do that?

Comment: what about using ***make_pair***???

Comment: make_pair giving me the same issue

Comment: try `std::map::emplace`. It takes the key and the value as parameter